# Fetch EAGER not working with 2nd level relations

Tags: doctrine-orm, soft-delete

Just example:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Menu
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="MenuDish", mappedBy="menu", fetch="EAGER")
     */
    private $menu_dishes;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->menu_dishes = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class MenuDish
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Dish", inversedBy="menu_dishes", fetch="EAGER")
     */
    private $dish;
}
```

Then i trying to get menu:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$repo = $em->getRepository(Menu::class);
$menu = $repo->find(1);
```

Then I look into XDebug and see that Menu::$menu_dishes is Collection of Entities (not proxies) all is OK, EAGER working. 
BUT Menu::$menu_dishes::$dish contains Proxy ! There is a bug? $dish marked with fetch=EAGER. 
When I mark some property as FETCH=EAGER I expect that this property will not contain Proxy class.
I need it for fighting with SoftDelete, the real issue is that $dish is actually soft deleted, and fetch eager may fix it by setting $dish as null, but it is not working.
Ho to make EAGER working on dish property?

Comment: I suspect that it is intentional behavior due to performance reasons

Comment: if we need performance then we may keep fetch as default or set it to LAZY/EXTRA LAZY. eager is the option for cases when performance is not critical

Comment: Of course, but for second level it will require Doctrine to run through mapping definition in `ClassMetadata` for **every** element in collection and it can be predictable that Doctrine developers don't do it. I didn't look into Doctrine sources so can't proof this point, but it seems to be quite plausible